# Can I use more than one "and" in a list?

Tags: conjunctions, lists

Can I use more than one "and" in a list? Which sentence is correct, and why is it correct? Thank you for reading.

1. **"I am a good person, an exemplary citizen, and I want to make the system work better."**

or

2. **"I am a good person and an exemplary citizen, and I want to make the system work better."**

Comment: Those things are not all part of the same list.  You have two things in the list of what you are: “a good person and an exemplary citizen” then you have a compound sentence with a conjunction.  Since there’s only two things in your list you should use ***and***.

Comment: Thank you for helping me out. Which number is the correct sentence? Are you saying the second one is correct?

Comment: Lions and tigers and bears, oh my!

Comment: @LedZepp, the second sentence is correct, as explained by Jim.

Answer (score 1):

In informal text or speech, you can use "and" many times in a list.  This often sounds rushed or childish, though.  Hot Licks' example of "Lions and tigers and bears, oh my!" is from a [movie scene](https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=NecK4MwOfeI) with a scared child.

In formal writing, it is normal to have one "and" for each list or sub-list.  The original post has a main list, and a sub-list.  Both versions of the original list are acceptable in formal writing.  The second version is less ambiguous.

> 1. "I am a good person, an exemplary citizen, and I want to make the system work better."

The first version can be parsed as either

- a list containing three items (good person, exemplary citizen, I want…), or
- a list containing two items (I am a good person, I want…), plus an [appositive phrase](https://www.collinsdictionary.com/dictionary/english/apposition) (which is similar to a parenthetical note).

> 2. "I am a good person and an exemplary citizen, and I want to make the system work better."

The second verse can be parsed as

- a sub-list containing two items (good person, exemplary citizen), and
- a main list containing two items (I am <the sub-list>, I want…).