# Can we use more than one 'and' to connect the items in a list?

Tags: conjunctions, lists

> Ms. Silver had been talking about different habitats. While she
>   talked, she pointed to posters on the bulletin board labeled THE OCEAN
>   ***and*** THE RAIN FOREST ***and*** THE PRAIRIE. Then she talked about the
>   different names for the specific places animals live, their homes. She
>   mentioned nests ***and*** webs ***and*** caves ***and*** dens ***and*** burrows.

I read the above paragraph on ***Page41*** in the book ***the Year of Billy Miller***. I found out that the writer used more than one 'and' in his writing to connect the items in a list. As far as I know is that when you are linking more than two items, you usually only put and in front of the last one.

What is the purpose of the author using and to connect all items? Is it kind of writting skill to emphasize the sentence? I have checked the [similar question](https://ell.stackexchange.com/questions/114758/can-i-use-more-than-one-and-in-a-list), but it seems to me that the two questions are a little different.

Answer (score 3):

You usually only put "and" in front of the last one, yes, and replace redundant "ands" with commas. However, in some literary pieces, "ands" are used repeatedly for certain effects. In this case, I think that it is to create a sense of rhythm and humor.

Comment: Agreed.  Plus in this particular example, I think the repeated **and**s actual add clarity, breaking up the monotonous block of text those three capitalized labels would otherwise be.